# Creating a shell right click menu item to edit desktop.ini

Tags: windows, shell, windows-shell

I am trying to create a right click shell menu item to edit `desktop.ini`. I have managed to get this far:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\editdesktop]
@="editdesktop"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\editdesktop\command]   
@="notepad "%L/desktop.ini"
```

use the cmd command to create an desktop.ini and append the following format to the desktop.ini file ，Then open it(desktop.ini) with notepad.exe

```
/* Format start */

[.ShellClassInfo]   
InfoTip= 
ConfirmFileOp=0w

/* Format  end */
```

// ps: i just want to creat the  folder InfoTip , ,when i hover the folder,it will so 2 me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMD.exe nor Windows Scripting Host has .ini support so implementing this without overwriting is a bit risky, you also need to set the correct attribute on the folder and this could be SYSTEM or READONLY depending on a registry key!

This example should work in the default windows configuration and tries its best to not overwrite a existing file:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\editdesktop\command]
@="cmd /C ((if not exist \"%L\\desktop.ini\" (>\"%L\\desktop.ini\" (echo.[.ShellClassInfo]&echo.InfoTip=&echo.ConfirmFileOp=0w)))&attrib +s \"%L\"&attrib +h +s \"%L\\desktop.ini\"&start notepad \"%L\\desktop.ini\")"
```

It is probably a better idea to write a WSH or powershell script...